# Branching rule for degenerate cyclotomic Hecke algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, hecke-algebras, modular-representation-theory

Grojnowski and Vazirani showed that there is a crystal isomorphism between the crystal  defined by modular branching of simple modules of Ariki-Koike algebras and that of an integral highest weight module of the quantum enveloping algebra of $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}_e}$, where $e$ is the multiplicative order of the parameter $q$.
Ariki then showed that this isomorphism is actually the identity, if $e\geq 2$ is finite, and Vazirani showed the same for the case $|q|=\infty$.

My question now is the following:
 Has an analogous result been shown for $q=1$, where we have to replace $e$ by the characteristic of $K$, or rather the additive order of $q=1$?